# How to show gif image in fields by external url in Nova 4

Tags: php, package, laravel-nova

I encountered issue with nova 4 because I used package chaseconey/nova-external-image in nova 2 but after upgrading to nova 4 version, I can't use this one.

Do you know some package or trick for showing image in gif format ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
   Text::make('Image','image_url')->asHtml()
        ->displayUsing(function ($value){
            return "<a href='{$value}' target='_blank'><img width='250' src='{$value}'/></a>";
        })->onlyOnDetail()
```

it's worked for me.